# How to determine if a school is 529 eligible

Tags: united-states, college, 529-plan

How can I determine if a particular educational institution is eligible for 529 college savings plans? I found [a tool](http://www.savingforcollege.com/eligible_institutions/) which claims to tell whether schools are eligible but I am not sure

- if this site contains official information
- how to determine whether a school is 529 eligible using that site.

I am able to search for schools, but the search results don't give any indication whether the institution is 529 eligible. Does its presence in the search results indicate that it is?

Comment: Not sure on if their presence indicates this.  You could just call admissions.

Comment: I think the rule of thumb is that if it is eligible for FAFSA - it is eligible for 529.

Comment: @littleadv so how do you determine if a school is eligible for FAFSA?

Comment: @Daniel there's some Federal site with the list of eligible institutions, google it

Answer (score 2):

Federal School Code Search - 
https://fafsa.ed.gov/FAFSA/app/schoolSearch

> You can use the Federal School Code Search to search for colleges
>   you're interested in including on your FAFSA. You can also find
>   detailed college information, like tuition and fee amounts and
>   graduation rates, and compare that information for up to 10 colleges
>   at a time. If you have more than 10 colleges to compare, you must
>   remove some schools from the Selected Schools table in order to add
>   and compare the additional schools.